# How do I select an anonymous hash within an array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, select, hash

I have the following array where I want to select each of the keys:

```
names = [
 {"Ánias"=>{:gender=>"male", :nationality=>"faroese"}},
 {"Annfinnur"=>{:gender=>"male", :nationality=>"faroese"}},
 {"Ansgar"=>{:gender=>"male", :nationality=>"faroese"}}
]
```

How would I go about selecting all the names ("Ánias", "Annfinnur", "Ansgar")?

Comment: Do those hashes have always one key/value? (in that case it makes no sense to use a hash).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do

```
names = [
          {"Ánias"=>{:gender=>"male", :nationality=>"faroese"}},
          {"Annfinnur"=>{:gender=>"male", :nationality=>"faroese"}},
          {"Ansgar"=>{:gender=>"male", :nationality=>"faroese"}}
        ]

names.map { |h| h.keys.first }
# => ["Ánias", "Annfinnur", "Ansgar"]
```